# Web Config Transformation for behaviorConfiguration attribute not working

Tags: web.config-transform

Web.config original

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="Test.DevelopmentPc.Environment.Behavior" name="Tks.Licensing.Service.ActivationServer">
    <endpoint address="" name="httpEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="testBasicHttpBinding" contract="Tks.Licensing.Contracts.ServiceContract.IActivationService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

What I want it to be

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="__BehaviorConfiguration__" name="Tks.Licensing.Service.ActivationServer">
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureWsHttpBinding" name="httpEndpoint" contract="Tks.Licensing.Contracts.ServiceContract.IActivationService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="__ServerIdentity__"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

This is what I tried already:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="__BehaviorConfiguration__" name="Tks.Licensing.Service.ActivationServer" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(behaviorConfiguration)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureWsHttpBinding" name="httpEndpoint" contract="Tks.Licensing.Contracts.ServiceContract.IActivationService">
    <identity xdt:Trasform="Insert">
      <dns value="__ServerIdentity__"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

The original web config is not changing at all.

There are several service blocks in the original web cofig with different names.
I am not allowed to make any changes to the original config file. Is there a way to do it without touching the original file?

Comment: Are you using release management server or the new web-based release management?

Comment: Also, are you building your application with the appropriate MSBuild flags to invoke config transforms?

Comment: I am using release management server but i don't think RM is an issue here. I have other config transformation in my file and they all are working as expected. Only this one is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by replacing the whole "services" element.

```
<services xdt:Transform="Replace">
<service behaviorConfiguration="__BehaviorConfiguration__" name="Tks.Licensing.Service.ActivationServer">
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureWsHttpBinding" name="httpEndpoint" contract="Tks.Licensing.Contracts.ServiceContract.IActivationService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="__ServerIdentity__"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service></services>
```